# What is a portable app to enable flash drive search?

Tags: windows-vista, usb-flash-drive, search, portable-apps

I want a windows vista compatible portable application that provides fast search on my flash drive for those occasions when I work on another machine.  Something like google desktop for a flash drive.  Any suggestions or alternatives?

Comment: Why do you need this?  Explorer can search a flash drive.

Comment: If you have more than a handful of files, Explorer will be very slow to search through them.

Answer (score 1):

I have [**Agent Ransack**](http://www.mythicsoft.com/page.aspx?type=agentransack&page=home) on my flash drive.  It can be used a portable app.

Answer (score 0):

[Index Your Files](http://www.indexyourfiles.com) looks like what you want.